# Call and subtract specific std errors from a regression in one line of code

Tags: r, standard-error

Given a unique regression object `rsystol`, how do I subtract the standard errors from, e.g., the first and second coefficients. I am already subtracting the coefficients with the following code:

```
coefficients(r_systol)[1] - coefficients(r_systol)[3]
```

Now I need to perform the same operation with the corresponding standard errors.

Comment: You can get the standard errors from `summary(rsystol)`.

Comment: @ssdecontrol thank you; I have read that, but I am looking for a way to call them and subtract them similiar to how I have done the coefficients.

Comment: `summary` returns a `list` object. You can get the standard errors from there.

Comment: Try `summary(rsystol)$coefficients[1, 2] - summary(rsystol)$coefficients[3, 2]` ?

Comment: @zx8754 thank you. I have applied this and am getting a result. Can you please explain the significance of the numbers in the bracket, i.e., does 1 (3) represent the coefficient and 2 the indicator for calling the standard error?

Comment: `[row, column]`, 2nd column is the Standard Error. See linked post for example.